# How to create a BindingSeq[T] from a Binding[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, data-binding, collections, scala.js, binding.scala

I have a Binding[Seq[T]].

I want to create a BindingSeq[T] in a way that, whenever I change the Seq the BindingSeq will change in the same way.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the latter part of your question? Do you want `BindingSeq` to change if you change the `Seq` stored in your first variable, or if you change something inside the mutable `Seq` itself? I don't think the latter is possible.

Comment: The Seq is immutable. Sorry, should have made this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a `Binding[Seq[T]]` to a `BindingSeq[T]`.

```scala
def convert1[T](bindingOfSeq: Binding[Seq[T]]): BindingSeq[T] = {
  Constants(bindingOfSeq).flatMap { bindingOfSeq =>
    Constants(bindingOfSeq.bind: _*)
  }
}
```

or

```scala
def convert2[T](bindingOfSeq: Binding[Seq[T]]): BindingSeq[T] = {
  SingletonBindingSeq(bindingOfSeq).flatMap { seq =>
    Constants(seq: _*)
  }
}
```

However, the `Seq`, if it is a mutable Seq, has no magic data-binding ability.

When you change the content of the `Seq`, nothing happens.